# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: javascript, ajax, datasnap

Quando eu tento dar um GET em um link aqui no meu servidor que nao esta em local host acontece esta mensagem:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://192.168.25.66:8089/datasnap/rest/TServerConnMonitorMethods/Get_DataHora. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 500.

Codigo da Request:

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://192.168.25.66:8089/datasnap/rest/TServerConnMonitorMethods/Get_DataHora",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "266b68dc-31a5-bf40-69f4-2fa3be60cd9c"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os navegadores Web têm uma restrição de segurança, chamada *Same Origin Policy*. Ela faz com que certos requests, como os feitos via Ajax, só sejam permitidos dentro do mesmo domínio.

A solução recomendada é usar **CORS** (*Cross-Origin Resource Sharing*).

No servidor adicione o cabeçalho **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**, indicando quais outros domínios (origens) estão permitidos para acessar aquele serviço.

Exemplo:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.seusite.com
```