# Como obter as informações de meta tag de uma url externa?

Tags: javascript, html-meta-tag

Preciso obter o meta tag de uma url externa específica, porém achei apenas exemplos usando jquery para realizar esta funcionalidade, e não javascript puro. Em js puro, encontrei esse post onde é realizado o que preciso, porém não em qualquer página externa, e sim na própria página.

```
function getVideoContent() { 
   var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); 

   for (var i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { 
      if (metas[i].getAttribute("property") == "video") { 
         return metas[i].getAttribute("content"); 
      } 
   } 

    return "";
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524585/how-do-i-get-the-information-from-a-meta-tag-with-javascript

Alguém sabe como posso obter as informações de meta tag de qualquer url utilizando apenas javascript puro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devido a restrição CORS *(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, [leia sobre aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126318/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check/126341#126341))*, os navegadores bloqueiam por padrão requisições fora do seu domínio.

Mas podemos utilizar um proxy como o [crossorigin.me](https://crossorigin.me/) pra realizar esse tipo de requisição.

No código abaixo eu realizo uma requisição proxiada, obtenho o retorno que será o HTML da página, uma função recebe o retorno e faz todo processamento necessário, fiz um parse da string pra elementos DOM, utilizei uma parte do código da sua pergunta pra recuperar uma tag especifica e exibi-la numa div.

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", 'https://crossorigin.me/http://example.com/');
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      tratativa(xmlhttp.responseText);
    } else {
      console.log('Error: ' + xmlhttp.statusText)
    }
  }
}
xmlhttp.send();

function tratativa(htmlString) {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var documentoBody = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");

  var metaTags = documentoBody.getElementsByTagName('meta');

  for (var i = 0; i < metaTags.length; i++) {
    if (metaTags[i].getAttribute("name") == "viewport") {
      document.getElementById("retorno").innerHTML = metaTags[i].getAttribute("content");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="retorno"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Pode fazer o pedido normalmente como faz com qualquer endereço interno. Depois basta criar o ficheiro crossdomain.xml na raiz do seu site.

[Veja aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213251/can-someone-post-a-well-formed-crossdomain-xml-sample) uma questão sobre crossdomain.xml já resolvida.

Para uma completa referência veja o site da Adobe http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/cross-domain-xml-for-streaming.html