# Problema com Access-Control-Allow-Origin no XHR com Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, erp

Estou tentando consumir uma API via XHR e Javascript que vem do SAP HANNA e ele está retornando estes erros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O engraçado é que com o postman ele me retorna os valores, porém com o JS e o XML ele dá o erro acima..

**Segue o código simples:**

```
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
      });

    xhr.open("GET", "https://aliansce.apimanagement.us2.hana.ondemand.com/bot/v1/fatVenda.xsjs?Shop='BSC'&PeriodoAte=201807", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Apikey", "KEY");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic AUTH=");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("postman-token", "TOKEN");

    xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: Está reclamando de *Cross-Origin*, tenteou adicionar no header?

Comment: De uma olhada nessa resposta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/126341/3999